Compare Runtime of Merge Sort, Natural Merge Sort and Quick Sort. Elements=1000000
When I enter more than 250 elements
When I run the program without inserting Natural Merge Sort code, my program can run with 1000000 elements, but after I inserted Natural Merge Sort, my program can only run exactly with 250 elements. That means when I entered elements >250, my program just showed nothing and did not run anymore. The program should be like this
Here is my source code;
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <time.h>

int min(int x, int y) {
    return (x < y) ? x : y;
}

// Natural Merge Sort 
int SoDuongChay(int A[], int n) {
    int dem = 0, i = 0;
    while (i < n) {
        while (A[i] < A[i + 1] && i < n - 1)
            i++;
        dem++;
        i++;
    }
    return dem;    
}

void MergeNatural(int A[], int B[], int C[], int *nB, int *nC, int *nA) {
    int p = 0, pb = 0, pc = 0, ib = 0, ic = 0, kb, kc;
    while ((*nB > 0) && (*nC > 0)) {
        kb = min(*nB, 1000000);
        kc = min(*nC, 1000000);
        if (B[pb + ib] <= C[pc + ic]) {
            A[(*nA)++] = B[pb + ib];
            ib++;
            if (ib == kb) {
                for (; ic < kc; ic++)
                    A[(*nA)++] = C[pc + ic];
                pb += kb;
                pc += kc;
                ib = ic = 0;
                *nB -= kb;
                *nC -= kc;
            }
        } else {
            A[(*nA)++] = C[pc + ic];
            ic++;
            if (ic == kc) {
                for (; ib < kb; ib++)
                    A[(*nA)++] = B[pb + ib];
                pb += kb;
                pc += kc;
                ib = ic = 0;
                *nB -= kb;
                *nC -= kc;
            }
        }
    }
    while (*nB > 0) {
        A[(*nA)++] = B[pb++];
        (*nB)--;
    }
    while (*nC > 0) {
        A[(*nA)++] = C[pc++];
        (*nC)--;
    }
    *nB = 0;
    *nC = 0;
}

void DistributeCombine(int A[], int B[], int C[], int n) {
    int i = 0, dem = 0, nA = 0;
    int nB = 0, nC = 0;
    while (i < n) {
        int temp = i;
        while (A[i] < A[i + 1] && i < n - 1)
            i++;
        if (dem % 2 == 0)
            for (int j = temp; j <= i; j++)
                B[nB++] = A[j];
        else {
            for (int j = temp; j <= i; j++)
                C[nC++] = A[j];
            MergeNatural(A, B, C, &nB, &nC, &nA);
        }
        i++;
        dem++;
    }
    if (nB != 0)
        for (int k = 0; k < nB; k++)
            A[nA++] = B[k];
}

void NaturalMergeSort(int A[], int B[], int C[], int n) {
    while (SoDuongChay(A, n) >= 2)
        DistributeCombine(A, B, C, n);
}

//Merge Sort 
void Distribute(int a[], int n, int *pb, int *pc, int k, int b[], int c[]) {
    *pb = 0;
    *pc = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int j;
    while (i < n) {
        for (j = 0; (j < k) && (i < n); j++) {
            b[(*pb)++] = a[i++];
        }
        for (j = 0; (j < k) && (i < n); j++) {
            c[(*pc)++] = a[i++];
        }
    }
}

void Merge(int a[], int nb, int nc, int k, int b[], int c[]) {
    int p, pb, pc, ib, ic, kb, kc;
    p = pb = pc = 0;
    ib = ic = 0;
    while ((0 < nb) && (0 < nc)) {
        kb = min(k, nb);
        kc = min(k, nc);
        if (b[pb + ib] <= c[pc + ic]) {
            a[p++] = b[pb + ib];
            ib++;
            if (ib == kb) {
                for (; ic < kc; ic++)
                    a[p++] = c[pc + ic];
                pb += kb;
                pc += kc;
                ib = ic = 0;
                nb -= kb;
                nc -= kc;
            }
        } else {
            a[p++] = c[pc + ic];
            ic++;
            if (ic == kc) {
                for (; ib < kb; ib++)
                    a[p++] = b[pb + ib];
                pb += kb;
                pc += kc;
                ib = ic = 0;
                nb -= kb;
                nc -= kc;
            }
        }
    }
    while (nb > 0) {
        a[p++] = b[pb++];
        nb--;
    }
    while (nc > 0) {
        a[p++] = c[pc++];
        nc--;
    }
}

void MergeSort(int a[], int n) {
    int length = 1000000;
    int *b = (int *)malloc(length * sizeof(int));
    int *c = (int *)malloc(length * sizeof(int));
    int pb, pc;
    int k = 1;
    do {
        Distribute(a, n, &pb, &pc, k, b, c);
        Merge(a, pb, pc, k, b, c);
        k *= 2;
    } while (k < n);
}

//quickSort
int sumArray(int a[], int n) {
    if (n <= 0) { 
        return 0; 
    } else {
        return a[n-1] + sumArray(a, n - 1); 
    }
}

void swap(int *a, int *b) {
    int temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

int partition(int a[], int left, int right) {
    int pivot = a[(left + right) / 2]; 
    int i = left - 1;  
    int j = right + 1; 
    while (1) {
        do {
            i++;
        } while(a[i] < pivot); 
        
        do {
            j--;
        } while(a[j] > pivot); 
        
        if (i < j) 
            swap(&a[i], &a[j]); 
        else 
            return j; 
    }       
}

void QuickSort(int a[], int left, int right) {
    if (left >= right) 
        return; 
    int p = partition(a, left, right); 
    QuickSort(a, left, p); 
    QuickSort(a, p + 1, right); 
}

void printArray(int a[], int n) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    printf("\n");
}

int main() {
    int i, n;
    int length = 1000000;
    int *a = (int *)malloc(length * sizeof(int));
    int *a1 = (int *)malloc(length * sizeof(int));
    int *a2 = (int *)malloc(length * sizeof(int));
    int *b = (int *)malloc(length * sizeof(int));
    int *c = (int *)malloc(length * sizeof(int));
    srand(time(NULL));
    printf("\nEnter the number of elements: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        a[i] = rand() % 1000000;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        a1[i] = a[i];
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        a2[i] = a[i];
    struct timespec start, end;
    float NaturalMergeSort_time, MergeSort_time, QuickSort_time;
    
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start);
    NaturalMergeSort(a, b, c, n);
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &end);
    NaturalMergeSort_time = (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) * 1000000 + (end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec) / 1000.0; 

    //
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start);
    MergeSort(a1, n);
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &end);
    MergeSort_time = (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) * 1000000 + (end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec) / 1000.0; 
    
    //
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start);
    QuickSort(a2, 0, n - 1);
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &end);
    QuickSort_time = (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) * 1000000 + (end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec) / 1000.0; 
    
    printf("\nCompare table:\n");
    printf("------------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("| Algorithm         | Time (microseconds)     |\n");
    printf("------------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("| Natural Merge Sort       | %.2f                    |\n", NaturalMergeSort_time);
    printf("| Merge Sort               | %.2f                    |\n", MergeSort_time);
    printf("| Quick Sort               | %.2f                    |\n", QuickSort_time);
    printf("------------------------------------------------------\n");

    free(a);
    free(a1);
    free(a2);
    free(b);
    free(c);
    return 0;
}

I want to know what's wrong with my Natural Merge Sort code or my declaration.

“my program can only run exactly with 250 elements” is not a problem description. You need to state exactly what happens when you attempt to run the program with some other number of elements. Edit the question to provide a [mre]. Also edit the title to ask a question relevant to the problem.

Make sure your allocations "worked": ...malloc()... if (NULL) exit("no memory"); /* not C; this is human pseudo-code */ ... Oh, use calloc rather than malloc too

i used calloc but nothing happened. The program just do nothing.

Every malloc()/calloc() must have an associated free(). You have an allocation problem ("works with few elements, does not work with many elements"), so make sure everything related to allocation is done 100% right!

i added free() in function main but it still did not work.

What if you add free() to MergeSort() (or simply don't test it until you get your new sorting method working)? There's malloc()s there too!!

i tried that and still did not work. I think the problem comes from my new sorting method because my program just runs normally without it.

"The program just do nothing": this is stuff you should analyse with a debugger. Step through the code, set breakpoints, and find out which is the last statement that runs as you expected. Please show the results of your debugging session.

"Just doing nothing" sounds like what happens if you blow past the stack size for the program, which recursion on a million elements could do without even trying very hard.  On Windows, the stack size is normally 1 MiB; on Unix, it's normally 8 MiB.  You don't have any big local arrays allocated on the stack, which is good, but you do have local variables that occupy space.

Maybe a debugger cause this problem. I use dev C application and it just run with up to 250 elements, but when i use Online C Complier, it run with up to 1000 elements

But as i said, my program runs normally without inserting Natural Merge Sort code. By the side, i created a separate program to run Natural Merge Sort with given array, not random array, and it just worked. So i think the problem comes from something like allocation

As part of the MCVE (Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses) or SSCCE (Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example — the same idea by a different name) that you are creating, you should eliminate all the code related to the sorts other than the "Natural Merge Sort" (NMS) code.  They are (presumably) not required to reproduce the crash in the NMS code.  You should also eliminate user input — simply hard-wire the values for a test case that fails.  Check that the MCVE still fails, and display that code.

try a[i] = 42; instead of random numbers... and run your code for like 10 elements: with sufficient random numbers you eventually get a small array in the recursive calls with all numbers equal.

it works with few elements or given array. But my homework is 1 million random elements

It does not work with {42, 42, 42, 42, 42}. It's your homework... you now have a data set easy to work with :)

yes i agree with you

You said "Maybe a debugger cause[s] this problem".  As a programmer, you will quickly learn that it is rarely your tools (compilers or debuggers) that cause trouble.  Problems are almost invariably in your code.  You only hypothesize that the tool chain is at fault when there is nothing else to suspect.

ye i still thinking about what's wrong with my code

"i still thinking about what's wrong with my code" Ahhhhhhh... the pleasures of programming. I've had my (great) fun finding the {42, 42, 42, 42, 42} data set for you :)

oh im sorry, this morning i tested  carefully about a[i] = 42 with 10 elements as you said. And it worked !!! The problem came from my Natural Merge Sort that it did not sort duplicated elements. Thanks so much bro

Please do not add "Solved" to the question title. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311829/why-does-stack-overflow-discourage-adding-solved-to-question-titles

The reason your NaturalMergeSort function fails for sufficiently large sets is it cannot handle duplicate values.  The loop while (A[i] < A[i + 1] && i < n - 1) has 2 issues:

the comparison i < n - 1 should be performed before accessing A[i + 1] and
the comparison A[i] < A[i + 1] should use <= instead of <
As coded, any duplicate values will create separate runs so the function SoDuongChay never returns 1, so the natural merge sort never finishes and the program is stuck with no output.  Note that the function DistributeCombine has the same flaw and calls MergeNatural with sets that are already merged but this extra work has no effect.

Note also these remarks:

computing kb as kb = min(*nB, 1000000) seems useless and will cause problems for very large sets. You should just set kb = *nB;
the function MergeNatural is too complex. Updating the index variables from the caller is needlessly complicated and difficult to follow. A simpler approach is recommended.
calling SoDuongChay causes extra scans of the data set. DistributeCombine could return the number of merged sets and NaturalMergeSort would continue calling it as long as the return value is greater than 1.
this benchmark program should check that the sets are properly ordered after each call to the sort functions. It is easy to produce invalid code and vain to benchmark it.
All 3 sorting functions should have the same prototype: NaturalMergeSort should allocate and free its ancillary arrays and QuickSort should be a wrapper that calls its own recursive ancillary function.
MergeSort does not work for sets larger than 1 million items because you allocate temporary arrays with a fixed length of 1 million.  Use n instead.
the temporary arrays b and c are not freed in MergeSort().

Here is a modified version with a simpler and smaller natural merge sort functions:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <time.h>

int min(int x, int y) {
    return (x < y) ? x : y;
}

// Natural Merge Sort
int SoDuongChay(int A[], int n) {
    int dem = 0, i = 0;
    while (i < n) {
        while (i < n - 1 && A[i] <= A[i + 1])
            i++;
        dem++;
        i++;
    }
    return dem;
}

void MergeNatural(int A[], int B[], int C[], int *nB, int *nC, int *nA) {
    int pb = 0, pc = 0, ib = 0, ic = 0, kb, kc;
    while ((*nB > 0) && (*nC > 0)) {
        kb = *nB;//min(*nB, 1000000);
        kc = *nC;//min(*nC, 1000000);
        if (B[pb + ib] <= C[pc + ic]) {
            A[(*nA)++] = B[pb + ib];
            ib++;
            if (ib == kb) {
                for (; ic < kc; ic++)
                    A[(*nA)++] = C[pc + ic];
                pb += kb;
                pc += kc;
                ib = ic = 0;
                *nB -= kb;
                *nC -= kc;
            }
        } else {
            A[(*nA)++] = C[pc + ic];
            ic++;
            if (ic == kc) {
                for (; ib < kb; ib++)
                    A[(*nA)++] = B[pb + ib];
                pb += kb;
                pc += kc;
                ib = ic = 0;
                *nB -= kb;
                *nC -= kc;
            }
        }
    }
    while (*nB > 0) {
        A[(*nA)++] = B[pb++];
        (*nB)--;
    }
    while (*nC > 0) {
        A[(*nA)++] = C[pc++];
        (*nC)--;
    }
    *nB = 0;
    *nC = 0;
}

void DistributeCombine(int A[], int B[], int C[], int n) {
    int i = 0, dem = 0, nA = 0, nB = 0, nC = 0;
    while (i < n) {
        int temp = i;
        while (i < n - 1 && A[i] <= A[i + 1])
            i++;
        if (dem % 2 == 0) {
            for (int j = temp; j <= i; j++)
                B[nB++] = A[j];
        } else {
            for (int j = temp; j <= i; j++)
                C[nC++] = A[j];
            MergeNatural(A, B, C, &nB, &nC, &nA);
        }
        i++;
        dem++;
    }
    if (nB != 0) {
        for (int j = 0; j < nB; j++)
            A[nA++] = B[j];
    }
}

void NaturalMergeSort(int A[], int n) {
    int *B = (int *)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    int *C = (int *)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    while (SoDuongChay(A, n) >= 2) {
        DistributeCombine(A, B, C, n);
    }
    free(B);
    free(C);
}

// Simpler Natural Merge Sort
void MyMergeNatural(int A[], int B[], int C[], int nB, int nC, int nA) {
    int pb = 0, pc = 0;
    while (pb < nB && pc < nC) {
        if (B[pb] <= C[pc])
            A[nA++] = B[pb++];
        else
            A[nA++] = C[pc++];
    }
    while (pb < nB) {
        A[nA++] = B[pb++];
    }
    while (pc < nC) {
        A[nA++] = C[pc++];
    }
}

int MyDistributeCombine(int A[], int B[], int C[], int n) {
    int i = 0, runs = 0;
    while (i < n) {
        int nA = i;
        int nB = 0;
        while (i < n - 1 && A[i] <= A[i + 1]) {
            B[nB++] = A[i++];
        }
        B[nB++] = A[i++];
        runs++;
        if (i >= n)
            break;
        int nC = 0;
        while (i < n - 1 && A[i] <= A[i + 1]) {
            C[nC++] = A[i++];
        }
        C[nC++] = A[i++];
        MyMergeNatural(A, B, C, nB, nC, nA);
    }
    return runs;
}

void MyNaturalMergeSort(int A[], int n) {
    int *B = (int *)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    int *C = (int *)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    while (MyDistributeCombine(A, B, C, n) > 1)
        continue;
    free(B);
    free(C);
}

// Alternative using a single extra array
void MyMergeNatural2(int A[], int B[], int nB, int pc, int nC, int nA) {
    int pb = 0;
    while (pb < nB && pc < nC) {
        if (B[pb] <= A[pc])
            A[nA++] = B[pb++];
        else
            A[nA++] = A[pc++];
    }
    while (pb < nB) {
        A[nA++] = B[pb++];
    }
}

int MyDistributeCombine2(int A[], int B[], int n) {
    int i = 0, runs = 0;
    while (i < n) {
        int nA = i;
        int nB = 0;
        while (i < n - 1 && A[i] <= A[i + 1]) {
            B[nB++] = A[i++];
        }
        B[nB++] = A[i++];
        runs++;
        if (i >= n)
            break;
        int temp = i;
        while (i < n - 1 && A[i] <= A[i + 1])
            i++;
        i++;
        MyMergeNatural2(A, B, nB, temp, i, nA);
    }
    return runs;
}

void MyNaturalMergeSort2(int A[], int n) {
    int *B = (int *)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    while (MyDistributeCombine2(A, B, n) > 1)
        continue;
    free(B);
}

//Merge Sort
void Distribute(int a[], int n, int *pb, int *pc, int k, int b[], int c[]) {
    *pb = 0;
    *pc = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int j;
    while (i < n) {
        for (j = 0; (j < k) && (i < n); j++) {
            b[(*pb)++] = a[i++];
        }
        for (j = 0; (j < k) && (i < n); j++) {
            c[(*pc)++] = a[i++];
        }
    }
}

void Merge(int a[], int nb, int nc, int k, int b[], int c[]) {
    int p, pb, pc, ib, ic, kb, kc;
    p = pb = pc = 0;
    ib = ic = 0;
    while ((0 < nb) && (0 < nc)) {
        kb = min(k, nb);
        kc = min(k, nc);
        if (b[pb + ib] <= c[pc + ic]) {
            a[p++] = b[pb + ib];
            ib++;
            if (ib == kb) {
                for (; ic < kc; ic++)
                    a[p++] = c[pc + ic];
                pb += kb;
                pc += kc;
                ib = ic = 0;
                nb -= kb;
                nc -= kc;
            }
        } else {
            a[p++] = c[pc + ic];
            ic++;
            if (ic == kc) {
                for (; ib < kb; ib++)
                    a[p++] = b[pb + ib];
                pb += kb;
                pc += kc;
                ib = ic = 0;
                nb -= kb;
                nc -= kc;
            }
        }
    }
    while (nb > 0) {
        a[p++] = b[pb++];
        nb--;
    }
    while (nc > 0) {
        a[p++] = c[pc++];
        nc--;
    }
}

void MergeSort(int a[], int n) {
    if (n > 1) {
        int *b = (int *)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
        int *c = (int *)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
        int pb, pc;
        int k = 1;
        do {
            Distribute(a, n, &pb, &pc, k, b, c);
            Merge(a, pb, pc, k, b, c);
            k *= 2;
        } while (k < n);
        free(b);
        free(c);
    }
}

//quickSort
void swap(int *a, int *b) {
    int temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

int partition(int a[], int left, int right) {
    int pivot = a[(left + right) / 2];
    int i = left - 1;
    int j = right + 1;
    while (1) {
        do {
            i++;
        } while(a[i] < pivot);

        do {
            j--;
        } while(a[j] > pivot);

        if (i < j)
            swap(&a[i], &a[j]);
        else
            return j;
    }
}

void QuickSort1(int a[], int left, int right) {
    if (left < right) {
        int p = partition(a, left, right);
        QuickSort1(a, left, p);
        QuickSort1(a, p + 1, right);
    }
}

void QuickSort(int a[], int n) {
    if (n > 1) {
        QuickSort1(a, 0, n - 1);
    }
}

int CheckSort(const int a[], int n, const char *name) {
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        if (a[i - 1] > a[i]) {
            printf("%s failed: a[%d] = %d > %d = a[%d]\n",
                   name, i - 1, a[i - 1], a[i], i);
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void printArray(int a[], int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    printf("\n");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int n;

    srand(time(NULL));
    if (argc > 1) {
        n = strtoul(argv[1], NULL, 0);
    } else {
        printf("\nEnter the number of elements: ");
        if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1)
            return 1;
    }
    struct {
        void (*sort)(int *a, int n);
        const char *name;
        int check;
        double time;
    } test[] = {
        { NaturalMergeSort, "Natural Merge Sort", 0, 0 },
        { MergeSort, "Merge Sort", 0, 0 },
        { QuickSort, "Quick Sort", 0, 0 },
        { MyNaturalMergeSort, "Simpler Natural Merge Sort", 0, 0 },
        { MyNaturalMergeSort2, "Smaller Natural Merge Sort", 0, 0 },
    };
    int *a0 = (int *)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    int *a1 = (int *)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        a0[i] = rand() % 1000000;
    }

    int status = 0;
    for (size_t t = 0; t < sizeof(test) / sizeof(test[0]); t++) {
        struct timespec start, end;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            a1[i] = a0[i];
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start);
        test[t].sort(a1, n);
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &end);
        test[t].check = CheckSort(a1, n, test[t].name);
        status |= test[t].check;
        test[t].time = (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) * 1000.0 + (end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec) / 1000000.0;
    }
    printf("Sorting times for %d entries\n", n);
    printf("--------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("| Algorithm                  |     Time    |\n");
    printf("--------------------------------------------\n");
    for (size_t t = 0; t < sizeof(test) / sizeof(test[0]); t++) {
        if (!test[t].check)
            printf("| %-26s | %8.3f ms |\n", test[t].name, test[t].time);
    }
    printf("--------------------------------------------\n");

    free(a0);
    free(a1);
    return status;
}

Output:
Sorting times for 10000000 entries
--------------------------------------------
| Algorithm                  |     Time    |
--------------------------------------------
| Natural Merge Sort         | 1928.621 ms |
| Merge Sort                 | 1601.156 ms |
| Quick Sort                 | 1094.788 ms |
| Simpler Natural Merge Sort | 1099.796 ms |
| Smaller Natural Merge Sort | 1025.388 ms |
--------------------------------------------


Thanks very much for spending time fixing my code. I really appreciate that!!
